# How to load external library in Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon, kint

I'm trying to load [Kint](https://github.com/raveren/kint/) into my first Phalcon project. I'm trying to use the `loader.php` to do so. I tried with "registerDirs", "registerClass" and "registerNamespaces".

I am used to using Kint in Symfony2 via composer but this time I tried to clone the git repo and place it in a vendors folder in this Pahlcon project. All I get when `require`ing the Kint class is a silent 500 internal error. The following is the code I currently have.

```
<?php
# app/config/loader.php

$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir,
        '~/Code/incubator/Library/Phalcon',
        "vendor/kint"
    )
)->register();
```

And the controller in question:

```
<?php
# app/controllers/indexController.php

class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        Kint::dump("huh");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require composers autoloader inside of your bootstrap:

Inside your public/index.php, include composers autoloader:
https://github.com/phalcon/forum/blob/master/public/index.php#L44

```
require realpath('..') . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```